# keep track of the request queue in grpc server

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, grpc-python

GRPC server does queue the requests and serve them based on the maxWorker configuration which is passed when the sever starts up. How do I print the metric- number of items in the queue .? Essentially, I would like to keep track of the numbers of requests in waiting state.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your own executor to `serverBuilder.executor()`. Note that you are then responsible for shutting down the executor service after the server has terminated.

Comment: I am using python on my server side. Ideally what I want is the number of messages currently sitting in the channel queue.

Comment: My answer was for grpc-java. I don't know the answer for grpc-python.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for grpc-python is similar to grpc-java. You can pass your customized future executor to the server constructor, and monitor the submission of task yourself.

gRPC Python API: [grpc.server(thread_pool, ...)](https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#create-server)

The executor class to extend: [concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor)